# Selecting record from two tables with INNER join limit 3

Tags: mysql, join

I have records in two tables as shown below

```
Table1
userid    email
1        123@qwe.com
4        qwe@sdf.cok
5        sad@fgdf.sdf
7        dsvh@dsf.we
9        fdsdf@fgh.hh
```

.

```
Table 2
userid    values
1        15
1        45
1        76
1        15345
4        4545
4        76788
4        15879
5        4534
5        76345
5        15678
5        4567
5        7667789
7        15
7        456786
7        76678
7        15678
9        45789
9        76789
9        15789
9        4557
9        7667
9        1556
9        4556
9        764
```

Now I want the first 3 records from `table1` with userid in descending order along with the `table2` records related to them

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT a.userid, a.email, b.values 
    FROM table1 a
    INNER JOIN table2 b ON a.userid = b.userid
    ORDER BY a.userid asc
    LIMIT 0,3
```

Comment: it is returning1    15
1    45
1    76

Comment: So you want only 1 record for each userid?
`SELECT a.userid, a.email, b.values FROM table1 a, table2 b
WHERE a.userid = b.userid
GROUP BY a.userid
ORDER BY a.userid asc
LIMIT 0,3`

But if you want to display only 1 userid line so how about `values`
column? `sum` or something?

Comment: userid values9    45789
9    76789
9    15789
9    4557
9    7667
9    1556
9    4556
9    764
5    4534
5    76345
5    15678
5    4567
5    7667789
7    15
7    456786
7    76678
7    15678

Comment: the query given by u is returning 3 recodrs related one userid

Comment: Because you requested limit to 3 records. If you want to show all records please remove `LIMIT 0,3`

Comment: i want to apply limit to first table

Comment: so the requirement is select latest 3 records from first table and select records from second table  related those 3 records

Comment: This requirement seem to be impossible if you do not want to use sub query.

Comment: Its ok u help me like that (subquery ) atleast

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table2
WHERE userid 
in (SELECT * FROM (SELECT user FROM table 1 ORDER BY userid DESC LIMIT 0,3) alias)`

Comment: Changed your 1989 syntax into current SQL syntax. Note that implicit `where` joins are widely frowned upon in SO.

Comment: @Johan: Please give guru and me a query?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT TOP 3 * FROM Table1) AS Table1 INNER JOIN
     Table2 ON Table1.userid = Table2.userid
ORDER BY Table1.userid
```

Comment: I'm sorry! I just see your question was about mysql. This query works in MSSQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT t1.userid, t1.email, group_concat(t2.`values`) as t2values
  FROM table1 t1
  INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON (t1.userid = t2.userid)
  GROUP BY t1.userid
  ORDER BY t1.userid ASC
  LIMIT 3 ) subselect
ORDER BY subselect.userid DESC
```

**Explanation:**
`Group_concat` is an aggregate function that will make a list of comma separated values.
Because you are using an aggregate function you need to group on userid.
The `limit 3` selects the first 3 userid's (because you've ordered ASC)
Then the outer select picks up all 3 rows and reverses the order to DESC.

**Links**
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: Agree with your solution but if they want to show each value for separate result row. You still have to use 1 more sub query?

Comment: can we write multiple columns in group_contact function